# Session Types in Java for a cloud-based application

Tags: java, azure, cloud

Is it possible/compatible to use Session Types in Java for a cloud-based application using Windows Azure (SDK for Java)?

Answer (score 0):

It might not be what you are after but you can configure [Session Affinity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh690950.aspx) using the Window Azure Eclipse Plugin.